# Is Israel limited with informers by whether they will grant visas?

Tags: visa, 2023-israel-hamas-war

I've read that the USA gets informers by promising visas for them and their families. Does Israel do something similar or no?

I'm asking since they have different immigration policies.

Comment: You are asking two questions (and the first only makes sense if the answer to the second one is no). Maybe they are doing it already or maybe they have other ways. I think traditionally informers are paid cash, which may be more flexible in use than citizenships.

Comment: Traditionally for who?

Comment: This question seems based on lots of supposition. You could ask a more factual question about how Israel manages and rewards informers, but I'm not sure that there is much public-domain information, particularly about the current situation in late 2023. (The Israeli media is full of questions about why there were intelligence failures, but I don't see many firm answers.)

Comment: Giving people visa's isn't always the solution as it isn't always what informers want.

Comment: I didn't say always,  the question is whether they do it at all. The only difference I'm supposing is wondering that there may be one due to immigration policies.

Answer (score 2):

The Israeli government is a unicameral parliamentary system. The prime minister has the *de facto* ability to pass laws very expeditiously that authorize almost anything that doesn't violate certain fundamental legal protections, and certainly has the power to pass laws to grant visas to informants and their families if it wishes to do so, whether or not such authority is currently on books of Israeli immigration law right now.

Israeli intelligence services have particularly broad powers by international standards, so I suspect that it has many means at its disposal to encourage informants to help them, although I don't have good access to the relevant statutes to confirm that fact.